# Expressing a polynomial as a unique product of its zeros

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

> Let $K$ be a field and $p\in K[X]$ such that $1\leq\deg(p)$. Suppose
> $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in K$ are all the zeros of $p$, then $p$ can be written
> uniquely in the form  $$p=q\prod_{j=1}^n(X-a_j)^{m(j)}$$ where $q\in
>  K[X]$ has no zeros and $m(j)\in\mathbf{N}^*$ $(1\leq j\leq n)$.

**Attempt:**

I am trying to prove this by induction on $n$; however, I am stuck on the base case. Let $n=1$. Then $\{b\in K\ | p(b)=0\}=\{a_1\}$. There exists a unique $q\in K[X]$ such that $\deg(q)=\deg(p)-1$ and $p=q(X-a_1)$. How can I deduce that $q$ has no zeros? If $c\in K$ such that $q(c)=0$, then $p(c)=0$ and so $c=a_1$. This doesn't give a contradiction. So, it seems like $a_1$ can be a zero of $q$.

Should I be inducting on $\deg(p)$ as well? Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot yet deduce that $q$ has no zeros. You need to divide out factors $X - a_1$ until $a_1$ is no longer a zero of the other factor.

Comment: @DanielFischer. Thank you for your help. How can I express that process in terms of an induction? (e.g. should I induct on $\deg(q)$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=1$, then $p(X)$ has a single root, which is $a_1$. Let $N$ be the largest natural number such that $(X-a_1)^N\mid p(X)$. Then you can write $p(X)$ as $q(X)(X-a_1)^N$. Then $q(x)$ has no roots. If it had a root $a$, then either $a=a_1$ or $a\ne a_1$. If $a=a_1$, then $N$ would not be the largest natural number such that $(X-a_1)^N\mid p(X)$. And if $a\ne a_1$, then $a$ would be a root of $p(X)$ distinct from $a$, but such a root does not exist.

By the way, induction is not needed. What I did in the case $n=1$ works in the general case.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just a quick clarification: How can I show that $\{i\in\mathbf{N}\ |\ p\in(X-a_1)^iK[X]\}$ has a maximum? In other words, how can I prove that it must be finite?

Comment: Because $(X-a_1)^n\mid p(X)\implies N\leqslant\deg p(X)$.